# Does this definition of a set make sense: $S:=\{x: f(x)\geqslant |S|\}$?

Tags: logic

Let the function $f(x)=x^2$ be defined on the set of positive integers $\{1,2,\ldots\}$. Let the set $S$ be defined as follows:

$$S:=\bigl\{x: f(x)\geqslant |S|\bigr\}.$$

Is the set $S$ well defined? Why not?

NB. I have a more complicated function than $f(x)=x^2$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Why not?" : for $f(x)=x^2$, what would that set be?

Comment: I can't find a formula for it.

Comment: Regardless of the "formula": in your mind, is the statement $2\in S$ true or false, for $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: It is true only if $|S|\leqslant 4$.

Comment: That's obvious. That being said, is it true or is it false?

Comment: Well, I think it is false.

Comment: Let the number $s$ be defined as follows: $$s=s^2-2$$ Is the number $s$ well defined? Why not?

Comment: @bof $s=-1$ or $s=2$.

Comment: @Jarbou But which is it?

Comment: What about this one: $$s=1+s$$

Comment: BTW, the set of non-negative integers is $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. The set $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ is the set of positive integers.

Comment: If S is infinite then S is empty because no $x^2 \ge \infty$.  If S is finite then S is finite as for any |S| = k there are an infinite number of $x$ so that $xx^2 \ge k$.  Neither of those are possible so such a set is impossible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statement $$S=\{x: f(x)\ge\vert S\vert\}$$ is a meaningful statement about a set $S$. However, it doesn't constitute a definition: you can't use the thing you're trying to define, to define itself.

---

Now, that said, there are contexts in which self-referential "definitions" work! (A keyword here is "impredicative.") For example, defining a function by recursion can be viewed as such a definition: if we want to build a function $f$ satisfying "$f(n)$ is the number of $k<n$ such that $f(k)$ is even," we can define $f$ as $$f(n)=I(f\upharpoonright n)$$ (where $f\upharpoonright n$ is the function $f$ restricted to numbers $<n$, and $I$ applied to a function with finite domain outputs the number of times that function spits out an even number). This may seem bonkers at first, but it turns out to make perfect sense:

- There are no $k<0$, so $f(0)=0$.
- There is one $k<1$ - namely $0$ - and $f$ spits out an even number on that input (since $f(0)=0$, as we concluded above) - so $f(1)=1$.
- There's still only one $k<2$ with $f(k)$ even - so $f(2)=1$.
- And it's not hard to see that indeed $f(n)=1$ for all $n>0$.

See e.g. [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jeannin/papers/wf.pdf) for a serious treatment of definition by recursion as self reference.

But we have to be careful. Even if we allow $S$ to appear in its own definition, **we still don't let anything go**: in order to not be nonsense, a self-referential definition has to have two properties:

- It's true of *at most one* set.
- It's true of *at least one* set.

That is, something satisfying the definition has to exist, and has to be unique. Neither of these is obviously true of the statement you've written down.

**Indeed, the second one is *false* in the case you outline**: in the case $f(x)=x^2$, there is *no* $S$ with this property! Such an $S$ would have to be finite (since we never have $f(x)$ infinite), but then taking $n>\vert S\vert$ we'd have $n\in S$ (since $n^2>n>\vert S\vert$). But there are infinitely many $n>\vert S\vert$ if $S$ is finite, so then $S$ would be infinite; contradiction.

(Note that all we used was that $x^2$ is not bounded. However, boundedness isn't enough to guarantee the existence of such an $S$: consider the function $f(0)=2$, $f(n)=1$ for $n>0$. Can there be any set $S$ such that $S=\{x: f(x)\ge\vert S\vert\}$?

It's actually a good exercise to show that there is *any* function $f$ for which some $S$ exists! HINT: see what happens if you make $f$ take on its maximum value infinitely many times . . .)

Comment: Thank you. If for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $S$ would be equal to the set of positive integers, would it?

Comment: @Jarbou No: the size of that $S$ is infinite; so e.g. ${1\over 8}=f(8)$ is not bigger than the size of $S$, even though $8\in S$. And, you shouldn't speak of $S$ as if it's determined by $f$: the whole point of my answer is that such an $S$ may not exist, and if it exists it may not be unique.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks again.

Comment: Is it then possible that your first point "It's true of at most one set." fails? Can such self-referencing definitions hold true for more than one set? I can't think of any such example right now.

Comment: @H.Kissos How about "$S=S$?" *Every* set satisfies that.

Comment: Oh I see now. The context was more in general there. I was still thinking at the case $S=\{x\colon\text{ statement about }S\}$ which doesn't really seem to allow such problem at a first glance, right? Or not? You did wrote the poster's condition was not obvious about unicity of definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a circular definition.  The condition defining $S$ should not depend on $S$.

Well, I should modify that.  You can, of course, have a **recursive** definition.
But in that case there is a procedure for determining membership in the set that will always terminate.  That is not so here.

Comment: This is not true. $S = \{x : x = |S| \wedge x^2-x = |S|\}$ is a set that has a unique solution: $S = \{2, 2\}$. At no point did I specify some 'terminating' condition. This is a fairly basic example, but this can be as self-referential and complex as I wish to make it. The definition just needs to be somehow proven unique and existing.

Comment: @orlp: Your point may be valid but your example doesn't work, because $\{2,2\}=\{2\}$ so $|S|=1$.

Comment: @Rahul Right, as a programmer I'm used to ordered sets, rather than sets. As a valid example: $S = \{x : x \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge |S| = 2x^2\}$ with solution $\{1, -1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a self-reference problem in here. So $S$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $$S:=\bigl\{x: f(x)\geqslant |S|\bigr\}.$$ may be one of the property of your set $S$ (if such $S$ exists) rather than the definition of $S$. Moreover, in this circular sense, $S$ doesn't seem to be well defined.

It is something like searching the solution to the problem: "Construct a building in such a way that the height of each storey is greater than or equal to  the number of storeys of the building." Clearly, the  construction is possible iff the number of storeys are finite but with an extravagant idea of an unbounded number of storeys, such a construction would be fancy!!